# laravel-5.4 : get records that is created_at from yesterday at 5 o'clock until now

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I need to get the records that is created from `yesterday at 5.00PM` until `now` so if I try the following:

- If I open the system at `8am` query start `yesterday 5pm` until `now` (8am)
- If I open the system at `1pm` query start `yesterday 5pm` until `now` (1pm)

... and so on

Here is my function.

```
public function allNewOrdersToday() {
        $allNewOrders = ( new OrderList() )
            ->where( 'created_at', '>=', Carbon::yesterday() )

        return $allNewOrders;
    }
```

Comment: What is `OrderList()`? Is this a `model`? If so, is there a reason you are creating a `new OrderList()` and not just using the static builder methods?

Comment: @thisiskelvin yes it's a Models and this is a part of the function

Answer (score 3):

Using `Carbon`, you should be able to query where the date is beyond `Yesturday 5:00pm` using the `yesturday()` and `setTime()` carbon methods:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

... 

public function allNewOrdersToday() {
    return OrderList::whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::yesterday()->setTime(17, 00, 00)->toDateTimeString())
        ->get();
}
```

In this example, I have changed `(new OrderList())` to `OrderList::...` as you are using `eloquent` models and are able to call query builder methods without needing a new instance of the class.

Comment: @YousefAltaf Please give it a try. If this works mark question as correct

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
public function allNewOrdersToday() {
    $allNewOrders = ( new OrderList() )
       ->whereDate( 'created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d 17:00:00',strtotime("-1 days")) 
    return $allNewOrders;
 }
```